# Protein/ligand affinity databases?

Tags: bioinformatics, proteins, database, protein-binding, receptor

Is there any database that contain binding affinities reported in litterature for different proteins and ligands?

I have checked uniprot already and it does not seem to included any binding affinity data, for several well characterised receptors such as the human insulin receptor.

Comment: You could try [this](https://www.bindingdb.org/bind/index.jsp) or [this](http://www.bindingmoad.org). I haven't used either, but searching for a protein that I work with gave disappointing results.

Comment: [Brenda](http://www.brenda-enzymes.org/index.php) has a LOT of values from literature than can indicate binding (KI, IC50, Km), but only for enzymes not for proteins in general.

Comment: @canadianer I think it just gives binding of (pharmacological) small molecules to proteins. I just searched stat1 to see if it gives the binding energy of stat1 with its receptors. It doesn't. It rather considers stat1 as a target and returns two small molecules. So, I guess there is no good database for binding affinities.